# Setting modifed flag in recordset based on previous row with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb

I have the following table `post`

```
pk    id               title     title_mod      author    author_mod
--------------------------------------------------------------------
001    1             Foo Bar             1       Homer             1
002    1             Foo Bar             0        Bart             1
003    1             Foo-Bar             1        Bart             0
004    2         Hello World             1       Marge             1
005    2   Hello Springfield             1       Marge             0
006    2         Hello World             1       Homer             1    
007    3     Marge's recipes             1       Homer             1
008    3     Marge's recipes             0       Marge             1
009    3     Marge's recipes             0       Marge             0
```

Now, I need to fill those `*_mod` fields based on the previous row, e.g. if `title` is changed, `title_mod` becomes '1', otherwise '0'. If `id` is changed, every `*_mod` field becomes '1'.

Is there any way to do this with a simple 'Update' statement in MySql/MariaDb? (Or do I need some script?) TIA.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You mean, I think, if a previous column has changed.  Assuming that's the case I posted an answer below.

Comment: Define "previous column".  Perhaps `pk`?

Comment: Do you want to set these flags only once?  Will you be adding new rows?  Might you be adding a new row with id=2 and pk >9?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like this.

```
UPDATE post
SET id = new_id,
  title = new_title,
  title_mod = if( id != new_id, /* then */ 1, /* else */ if( title != new_title, /* then */ 1, /* else */ 0 ) )
  etc
```

Another option would be to use a BEFORE UPDATE trigger and use the same logic.

Comment: Use `@variables`.  Worry about the order.  PK?